# jsPlumb multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I build this connectable elements app, I'm using jsPlumb for connecting elements.

My app has the following behavior: When press the BUTTON, will add a new set of elements which the user should be able to connect.

As far as I read the jsPlumb documentation 'container' and endpoints should be and ID.

It is possible to make the jsfiddle 'actually work' as it should?
Is there another way to make the 'connection' ?

http://jsfiddle.net/9hzmrLdL/2/

```
var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({

    DragOptions: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        zIndex: 2000
    },
    Container: "flowchart-demo"

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `click` handler, you're just appending the DOM elements. You need to add the endpoints to the newly created elements, too; I recommend you bundle up your element creation together with endpoint creation; it's way easier to manage it that way.

Comment: is there a way where i can add Container: 'class here' and _addEndpoints('class-here', ..); ?

Comment: `Container` is the name for the whole jsPlumb-managed surface. Do you want to have multiple separate containers?

Comment: yes, ive tryied with jquery .each function but the dots are not in the correct position, http://prntscr.com/5pwgkx. This should work as questions, when press the button add another question with separated endpoints.

Comment: I don't see the endpoints being created for the 2nd set of object. Are you sure they are created?

Comment: I want it like this http://jsfiddle.net/9hzmrLdL/3/, but the endpoints to be classes

Comment: @hiero endpoints can't be classes. They are jsPlumb objects. I suggest you refer to the library's manual again.

Comment: @hiero you can add classes to endpoints - https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/endpoints.html `cssClass`